# Integrality of elements in the Field of Fractions

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a domain with field of fractions $K$ and suppose that $t$ is a transcendental element over $K$. Consider $f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^l a_k t^k,\ \in K[t]$. Show that if $f(t)$ is integral over $R[t]$, then $a_k$ is integral over $R$ for each $k$.

My approach: I have thus far only been able to prove that $a_0,a_l$ are integral over $R$ the following way:

As $f(t)$ is integral, there exists such a $g(t)\in R[t]$ s.t. $g(t)=f^m(t)+f^{m-1}(t)\cdot r_{m-1}+\dots+r_0=0$ where $r_i\in R$. Thus, if we plug in our sum for $f(t)$, we could regroup $g$ in descending order of $t^i$. As $t\neq 0$, one needs the coefficients to be equal to zero. From here, it is easy to see that $a_0,a_l$ are integral. However, not so much the rest, as I can't get a monic polynomial for them. Could someone help me?

Comment: Use (or prove first) that the difference of two integral elements is integral. So, you can remove $a_0$ from $f$ and then remove $x$. Then $a_1,a_2,...$ follow by induction.

Comment: Thank you! I have completely forgotten about this fact. I would upvote if you didn't comment, but answer :)